# How to retrieve number data types from models?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, model, vuejs3, inertiajs

So far I've been retrieving data from my model like so:

**`Gallery.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gallery extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['text'];
}
```

**`web.php`**:

```
Route::get('/gallery', function () {
    $data = Gallery::all();
    return inertia('gallery', ['data' => $data]);
});
```

**`gallery.vue`**:

```
const props = defineProps({
    data: Array
})
```

This is possible because `Inertia` does some magic routing under the hood, so that the response is passed directly to `props` inside the vue component. It retrieves the data but table parameters like `id` are returned as `String` in the `vue component` instead of `int`, like it is recorded in the database.

**`gallery.vue`** shows:

```
Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "id". Expected Number with value 1, got String with value "1".
```

How do I retrieve the right `data type` from the model?

**`Edit`**:

I've defined the prop for `id` in a child component of `gallery.vue`:

```
const props = defineProps({
    id: Number
})
```

Comment: But have you defined any explicit prop for id?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi I've added the information. Yes a child component of `gallery.vue` has `id` defined as `Number`.

Comment: Can't this be as simple as:  `id: Number | String`

Comment: Also, if  you are passing the props how are you passing it to the child component? Because passing it via `v-bind` could also be a reason you might be missing.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Isn't importing a `number` as `string` and accepting it inside your app as `string` a bad practice?

I'm passing the data via `v-bind` (`:`) directive down to my child components. The child receives the prop as `data: Array`, and one record of this array gets passed down to the grandchild as `data: Object`

Comment: But to investigate it properly. Check if the XHR request yields out the id as number or string?